# autocapture values from a textbox based on some characters 

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want a functionality ,where user can enter some text in a textbox,and based on some predefined characters ,i have to identify different attributes user can be linked to.
For example : In the textbox user enters as:
"Hello @Sunil you are going to work on #Desktop which has a priority of !1"

Now from this data,i want to extract the name of the developer,i.e based on @..which is sunil.
name of the team based on # char,which is desktop..and priority of task,based on !char which is 1.

This data will be entered on a website,used for task management and admins will enter this...
So that then it becomes fast entry of tasks...for admins.

I can split the data and process it...but then there are too many permutations and combinations in which order chars(#,@,!) may be entered.

I tried something like this,but it didnt helped:

```
if (TitleText.Contains("#") && TitleText.Contains("@") && TitleText.Contains("!"))
{

        string[] arr = TitleText.Split('#', '@', '!');
        title = arr[0];
        devName = arr[1].Trim().ToLower();
        devTeam = arr[2].Trim().ToLower();
        prio = Convert.ToInt32(arr[3]);
    } else if (TitleText.Contains("#") && TitleText.Contains("@")) {
        string[] arr = TitleText.Split('#', '@');
        title = arr[0];
        devName = arr[1].Trim().ToLower();
        devTeam = arr[2].Trim().ToLower();
        // prio = Convert.ToInt32(arr[3]);
    } else if (TitleText.Contains("#") && TitleText.Contains("!")) {
        string[] arr = TitleText.Split('#', '!');
        title = arr[0];
        devName = arr[1].Trim().ToLower();
        //devTeam = arr[2];
        prio = Convert.ToInt32(arr[2]);
    } else if (TitleText.Contains("@") && TitleText.Contains("!")) {
        string[] arr = TitleText.Split('@', '!');
        title = arr[0];
        // devName = arr[1];
        devTeam = arr[1].Trim().ToLower();
        prio = Convert.ToInt32(arr[2]);
    } else if (TitleText.Contains("#")) {
        string[] arr = TitleText.Split('#');
        title = arr[0];
        devName = arr[1].Trim().ToLower();
        //devTeam = arr[1];
        //prio = Convert.ToInt32(arr[2]);
    } else if (TitleText.Contains("@")) {
        string[] arr = TitleText.Split('@');
        title = arr[0];
        // devName = arr[1];
        devTeam = arr[1].Trim().ToLower();
        //prio = Convert.ToInt32(arr[2]);
    } else if (TitleText.Contains("!")) {
        string[] arr = TitleText.Split('!');
        title = arr[0];
        // devName = arr[1];
        //devTeam = arr[1];
        prio = Convert.ToInt32(arr[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with regex

```
string Name=Regex.Match(SubjectString, "@(.*?) ").Groups[1].Value;
string Comp=Regex.Match(SubjectString, "#(.*?) ").Groups[1].Value;
string Priort=Regex.Match(SubjectString, "!(.*?) ").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work if there are multiple tags per sentence. But it does work against the example you provided:

```
        string TitleText = "Hello @Sunil you are going to work on #Desktop which has a priority of !1 ";
        string title;
        string devname;
        string devteam;

        title = TitleText.Substring(TitleText.IndexOf("#")+1);
        title = title.Substring(0,title.IndexOf(" "));

        devname = TitleText.Substring(TitleText.IndexOf("@") + 1);
        devname = devname.Substring(0, devname.IndexOf(" "));

        devteam = TitleText.Substring(TitleText.IndexOf("!") + 1);
        devteam = devteam.Substring(0, devteam.IndexOf(" "));
```

Comment: This will throw an error if any of the searched chars is not present.

Comment: @gbianchi - Yes it will, it would be trivial to add conditional logic to check to see if the chars are present before parsing.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text = "Hello @Sunil you are going to work on #Desktop which has a priority of !1";
            var devPattern = new Regex(@"\@([^\s]+)");
            var teamPattern = new Regex(@"#([^\s]+)");
            var priorityPattern = new Regex(@"\!([0-9]+)");

            var team = ExtractValue(text, teamPattern);
            var dev = ExtractValue(text, devPattern);
            var priority = ExtractValue(text, priorityPattern);
        }
        private static string ExtractValue(string input, Regex regex)
        {
            return regex.IsMatch(input) ? regex.Match(input).Groups[1].ToString() : null;
        }
```